# How to read an image file from hard to memory using C

Tags: c

I want to read an image(JPEG) file from hard disk to memory. How can I do this? What kind of variable type should I use ?

Comment: do you want just to read in the file (decode it yourself)? or show it (you are not going to decode)?

Comment: I want read it, encrypt it using any algorithm and re save it to hard. And after read it again, decrypt and save it to hard.

Comment: note that JPEG is not a bitmap format , it is a lossy compression format using direct cosine transformation to compress the pixel values. If you manipulate the image after loading and save it, then you probably cannot view the image with a viewer. For that you need to decode the image (probably with an API for JPEG), edit the pixel values and save it. If you want to simply encode it, then just treat it as a binary file with no format data interpretation inside it. In this case you can treat any file like that.

Comment: So if i use only the above process will that harm to JPEG?

Comment: depends on what you actually want to do. do you want to encode some message in the image ? [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) , then you need to know the structure of the JPEG image and interpret it like that.  If you want to encode the file so that no one can open without decoding i, then any file can be interpreted as a structure less binary stream of data and simply encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a big char array

```
char data[4096]
```

And `fread(3)` chunks into it. Of course an entire JPEG won't fit in 4096 bytes, but perhaps you can work with chunks instead of the entire file ?